# Show that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + z\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{z}$

Tags: partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

I see such a question:

Assume that $z$ is a non-constant function of $x$ and $y$ and $\phi$ is given implicitly by $\phi(2x-z^2,y-\frac{1}{3}z^3)=0$. Show that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + z\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{z}$.

I achieved to show the equation by substituting $u= 2x-z^2$ and $v=y-\frac{1}{3}z^3$ and taking the partial derivatives w.r.t $x$ and $y$;

$\phi_u(2-2\cdot z \cdot z_x) + \phi_v(-z^2z_x) = 0$ etc.

However, the solution key has a different solution that confused me a bit.

The solution is given as:
$u= 2x-z^2$ and $v=y-\frac{1}{3}z^3$

$F_x = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}= \phi_u \cdot 2 + \phi_v \cdot 0$

$F_y = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}= \phi_u \cdot 0 + \phi_v \cdot 1$

$F_z = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}= \phi_u \cdot (-2z) + \phi_v \cdot (-z^2)$

And then used the formula $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = - \frac{F_x}{F_z}  $ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = - \frac{F_y}{F_z}$.

So my question is, in spite of the fact that $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, why did we take $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 2$ instead of $2-2zz_x$, why did we take $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 1$ instead of $-z^2z_y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did the problem by using implicit differentiation (treating $z=z(x,y)$ when you differentiated). They used the general formula for implicit differentiation coming out of the implicit function theorem.

Note that their $F(x,y,z) = \phi(2x-z^2,y-\frac13z^3)$. You differentiated $F(x,y,z(x,y))$ directly. Your formula is identical to theirs.

Comment: But still, cant’t $z$ include $x$ and $y$ facors or terms?

Comment: No, in that set-up, $x$, $y$, $z$ are independent variables.

Comment: I think, I should see the implicit function theorem to understand the behind idea. Thank you.